# How can we test external css file content with selenium UI verification

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to access the external css file data in a Selenium test case for UI verification?

Comment: Yes i need to test the styling of the elements whose css is in external file not in the same element tag. Can you please suggest it how to do with any example testcase

Comment: When you get the style of an element in Selenium, it returns the computed style, which means, it doesn't matter if it came from an external .css or if it was hardcoded in the HTML. The computed style is just whatever style was successfully applied to the element most recently. So it sounds like just getting the style of the element normally should do what you want, if I am understanding your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium isn't well-suited for style testing, rather just the DOM. You'd be far better off doing a perceptual difference if checking styles.

There's an open-source utility named pdiff which does this. http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/
There are also commercial tools such as Beyond Compare. http://www.scootersoftware.com/

The idea here is to take a screenshot of the page, which can be done using Selenium, and compare it pixel for pixel against a baseline image.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. Is there any possible tools available which supports Automation of UI verification(which might supports across the browsers) so that we can reduce the manual effort.?

Comment: Sure! The way to go on this one is to use Selenium to collect baselines once you've had your manual team look at everything. Store those somewhere. On each regression run, have Selenium capture a snapshot. Once you have the snapshot from the regression run, either immediately or at the end of your test, run a pdiff tool.

The pdiff tool i listed above runs from command line, heres one for grunt https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-pdiff and here's a comparison someone did of a python tool and pdiff http://tilander.org/aurora2/Comparing_Images/

Comment: If you want to really dig into this, there's an excellent [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMnZiTL0tUc) and a good [InfoQ article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/06/pdiff) about how Google uses pdiffs.